# VBScript not working in IE 11

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-11

This is the shocking news from Microsoft, Internet Explorer 11 no longer supports the VBScript. I've tried possible ways to run the vbscript in the IE 11 but not effective. Please provide the solution/suggestions.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

I've tired this and below js (will runs the vbscript in IE 11)

```
function callVBS(scriptName) {

  //-Variables--------------------------------------------------------
    var wsh, pathName;


  if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
    wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    if (typeof(wsh) == 'object') {
      pathName = location.pathname.substr(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/";
      pathName = pathName.slice(1);
      wsh.run("wscript.exe \"" + pathName + scriptName + ".vbs\"", 1, true);
      wsh = null;
    }
  }
  else {
    alert("Your Browser doesn't support ActiveXObject");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ie isn't available anymore, but i will give the answer.
Scripts and ActiveX Objects are disabled in ie11 bt default.
There is something called Edge Mode, that should be off.

Find Tools, click Internet Options.
Select Security, click Custom level.
Under the "Active Scripting", there should be a radio, enable it.
And finally click OK.